# How to bind a property in the view model of a usercontrol to a property in another usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I am currently working within a WPF user control using MVVM. My MainWindow.xaml looks like below.

> MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="TabsList" ObjectType="{x:Type local:MainWindowModel}" MethodName="GetTabs"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TabsList}}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=TabName}" Margin="10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource TabsList}, Path=MyUserControl}"/>
</Grid>
```

> Data provider class is as below

```
public class MainWindowModel
{
    public List<TabInfo> GetTabs()
    {
        return new List<TabInfo>()
        {
            new TabInfo() { TabName="Tab1", MyUserControl = new UserControl1()},
            new TabInfo() { TabName="Tab2", MyUserControl = new UserControl2()}
        };
    }
}
 public class TabInfo
{
    public string TabName { get; set; }
    public UserControl MyUserControl { get; set; }
}
```

And now I have two usercontrols UserControl1 and UserControl2 each has a text box control. I would like to update the Text property of the textbox control in the UserControl1 whenever the Text property of the Textbox control in the UserControl2 is updated. To do this, I tried as below.

> UserControl1

```
<UserControl x:Class="MoreOnBinding2.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" Text="{Binding Path=UserControl1Text}"/>
</Grid>
```

> UserControl1ViewModel

```
public class UserControl1VM : ViewModelBase
{
    public UserControl1VM()
    {
        this.UserControl1Text = "10";
    }
    private string userControl1Text;

    public string UserControl1Text
    {
        get { return userControl1Text; }
        set
        {
            if (userControl1Text != value)
            {
                userControl1Text = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => UserControl1Text);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> UserControl2

```
<UserControl x:Class="MoreOnBinding2.UserControl2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MoreOnBinding2"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Width="200" Height="20" 
        Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Path=UserControl1Text}" />
</Grid>
```

But it is not working. It seems there is a problem in the RelativeSource tag in the UserControl2. Can someone help on this.

Comment: UserControl1 is not an ancestor of UserControl2 ofcourse. Post the structure where you have placed these two UserControls in window.

Comment: You have a property of type `UserControl` in your view model? Please remove that MVVM tag... you don't deserve to use it.

Comment: @RohitVats The ContentControl in the MainWindow.xaml which I have posted above holds the user controls. I have also posted the MainWindowModel class where I have instantiated the user controls. Let me know, if anything more is needed. I have posted all most all of my code above.

Comment: @Sheridan Can you suggest me a way to avoid the user control references in view models in above case. Any reference to example code may help me a lot.

Comment: @Rahul, you don't need example code, you need an MVVM education. You claim to use MVVM, but you clearly have no idea what it is. I'd suggest simply reading up on it, or just stop pretending that you're using it. The main idea is to separate your data and views, but by putting view elements into your data provider class, you've failed at the first hurdle. There are *many* online tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Dependency Property on your user controls this would give you a bind able property.  see [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

EDIT 1

Just had another look at your class setup. If you are following the MVVM approach I don't think you should have a reference to your user control in your view model

View Model should be more Like

```
public Class
{
   ObservableCollection<TabInfo> _Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabInfo>();
   public ObservableCollection<TabInfo> Tabs
   {
     get{return _Tabs;}
     set {_Tabs = value;}//Need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged [Link][2]
   }

   public TabInfo SelectedTab {get;set;}
}

public class TabInfo
{
    public string TabName { get; set; }
    public UserControlViewModel MyUserControlViewModel{ get; set; }
}
```

Then in your View

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Column="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedTab}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Path=TabName}" Margin="10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedTab.MyUserControlViewModel"/>
</Grid>
```

This should give you a list of Tabs and then when one is selected it will set the content of the ContentControl to the MyUserControlViewModel.

You would then need to use some sort of template selector to control the ContentTemplate to load different UserControls into the ContentControl

I haven't tested the code works and you would need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged on all the public properties so the bindings update as the properties value is changed.

Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Binding the property "SelectedTab.MyUserControlViewModel" is giving the ToString() values of the ViewModel, instead of displaying the view, when I click on the listbox item. Can you please explain if I am missing something here. Coming to my original problem, I have added a depedency property as you suggested in each user control, but I don't understand how to bind the dependency property of usercontrol2 with the property in usercontrol1's view model. Can you please explain?

Comment: Now I understand. I have missed to define the datatemplate in the resources. After specifying the following, I could able to change to complete MVVM pattern as you suggested. Thanks for your help.      <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserControl1VM}">
                <local:UserControl1/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:UserControl2VM}">
                <local:UserControl2/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>